# Is there a way to search for questions with no accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, search

In here and a few other sites I spend a fair bit of time browsing through old questions to see if I can help in answering them.
I've found that there a good number of questions classed as 'unanswered' and these are very easily found.

However there is another class, these are questions with one or more answers but they don't have an accepted answer. Sometimes the suggested answers are  clearly wrong and are more guesswork.

Is there a way to show questions with no accepted answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there are a couple of search modifiers you can use to narrow down your results with regards to accepted answers.

#### `hasaccepted`

`hasaccepted` is used for when you want to know if there is an accepted answer on the question.

- [`hasaccepted:yes`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ayes): The question has an accepted answer
- [`hasaccepted:no`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ano): The question has no accepted answer

#### `isaccepted`

`isaccepted` is used for when you want to find answers that are, or aren't, accepted.

- [`isaccepted:yes`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=isaccepted%3Ayes): The answer is accepted
- [`isaccepted:no`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=isaccepted%3Ano): The answer is not accepted

Putting this together and taking your comment, *"these are questions with one or more answers but they've never been ticked as 'answer accepted' by the OP"*, into account I imagine the [query](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1) you are looking for is this, where `answers` specifies the minimum number of answers on the post:

```
hasaccepted:no answers:1
```

Then taking into account you originally tagged this meta post with [story-identification](/questions/tagged/story-identification) you are probably looking for [this query](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1+%5Bstory-identification%5D):

```
hasaccepted:no answers:1 [story-identification]
```

---

Note that this information is easily found on any "search results" page, there is a hyperlink at the top reading "Advanced Search Tips" and when clicked expands to show some search modifiers.

[image: Location of the "Advanced Search Tips" hyperlink]

At the bottom of this page is the line:

> For more details on advanced search [visit our help page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Which links you to a more thorough help page on all the modifiers if you want some more in depth information on them.